# Null Page_Validators causing error when triggering asp button onclick

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, onclick

I have an asp button that submits a form with some backend validation

```
<asp:button id="btnAdd" visible="true" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ETAFAdd"  text="Add &#187;" CssClass="formBut addEmailButton" causesvalidation="true" />
                    &nbsp; <a id="hoverover" style="cursor:default;" onmouseover="ShowPopup(this);" onmouseout="HidePopup();">
```

and the fields it submits:

```
<td valign="top">
    <asp:textbox id="txtToName" CssClass="iField txtToName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ETAFAdd" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvToName"
        ControlToValidate="txtToName"
        ValidationGroup="ETAFAdd"   
        Display="Dynamic"
        ErrorMessage="<b>Required Field Missing</b><br />A name is required." />  
    <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="Server" ID="vceToName"
        TargetControlID="rfvToName"
        HighlightCssClass="validatorCalloutHighlight" /> 
</td>
<td valign="top">
    <asp:textbox id="txtToEmail" CssClass="iField txtToEmail" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ETAFAdd"/>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvToEmail"
        ControlToValidate="txtToEmail"
        ValidationGroup="ETAFAdd"
        Display="Dynamic"
        ErrorMessage="<b>The email address you entered is invalid.</b><br />Example: name@wimco.com" />  
    <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="Server" ID="vceToEmail"
        TargetControlID="rfvToEmail"
        HighlightCssClass="validatorCalloutHighlight" /> 
</td>
```

When I click the asp button, it works. I tried to add another button on the page that triggers the asp button with an onclick

```
$(".formBut.addEmailButton").click();
```

but then a javascript error occurs in the ScriptResource validation; the first two Page_Validators are null, and I'm not sure why, and these null objects throw an error. This is the function that tries to run:

```
function Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup) {
Page_InvalidControlToBeFocused = null;
if (typeof(Page_Validators) == "undefined") {
    return true;
}
var i;
for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
    ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i], validationGroup, null);
}
ValidatorUpdateIsValid();
ValidationSummaryOnSubmit(validationGroup);
Page_BlockSubmit = !Page_IsValid;
return Page_IsValid;
}
```

Where are the null Page_Validators coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Check for validators being null.

```
if (validators != null) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i], validationGroup, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't edit the validation function. It's in the ScriptResource file, it's built in validation

Comment: It's built in functionality of asp.net. The Page_Validators are generated when you make an asp:RequiredFieldValidator or other type of validator. I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting null validator objects.